# utm campaigns conversions aren't being credited to the campaign in google analytics when using shopify

Tags: paypal, google-analytics, shopify

My problem is with using shopify, google analytics, and utm codes to track which campaigns is bringing which conversions.

A lot of my utm campaigns sales aren't being credited to the campaign, I think possibly because of paypal redirecting and paypal getting the credit for the sale instead of the utm campaign. How can I troubleshoot this issue and resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Add paypal to your [referral exclusion list](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en) in the property settings, unless you still use "classic analytics" in which case you add utm_nooveride=1 to the url that redirects back from paypal to your site.

If this really is your problem you can select source/medium as secondary dimension in your transaction report. If paypal is credited for the transactions you will see paypal.com/referral values (also this will maim some of your session based metrics since a change in attribution starts a new session in GA).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did that and it still shows paypal.com in referral values and no revenue is being show in my campaign.

Comment: I can't tell if you're already aware of this, but the setting does not work backwards; that data is lost. If at all it will only work for newly incoming data.

Comment: yes I know, I tried with a test purchase after setting it. I just talked to someone and they told me it is impossible to get the revenue to show up in campaigns from paypal

Comment: That would be news to many, many people, including myself, who correctly attribute traffic that is routed via paypal.

Comment: That's very good news Eike, how would I go about troubleshooting something like this? I'm guessing I would use the tag assistant but what should I look for in the report?

Comment: I figured out how to do it using payment pro, but is it possible to do it using express checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Wen user goes to PayPal from youre website, all original source data is lost, because paypal does not have Cross Domain tracking set up with your website. So PayPal in your analytics looks like a referral website. This can be solved with cookies and Uesr ID, but it requires some programing:

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id

Comment: thanks, I read through it, seems easy enough, could you recommend a safe an efficient code to create unique user IDs?